# Insert/update subelements or insert complete document in collection - depending on existing main-element

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

If I send data from a form, I first check if a document with the title already exist in the collection. 
If this isn't the case, the data should be inserted. 
Else only a part of the data will be inserted - if it doesn't exist itself as I want to avoid duplicates.

So this is how I do it:

```
var journal = list[0].value,
    article = {  
                author:         list[1].value, 
                pageNumbers:    list[2].value, 
                reference:      id 
            }

if (Collection.find({journal: journal}).count()) {
    Collection.update(
        { journal: journal }, 
        { $addToSet: { 
            article: article
        }
    });         
}
else {
    Collection.insert({ 
        journal: journal, 
        article: [article]
    });
}
```

But there are two problems for me:

1. Is there a smarter way to do that? Right now I have to do first a find().count() before inserting/updating.
2. My code doesn't work as I get the error `Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]`

**Update**

Would this be the same?

```
Collection.update(
    { journal: journal }, 
    { 
        $addToSet:  { article: article },
        $set:       { journal: journal, article: article }
    },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

Comment: (2) Is a common question - the only solution is to do the update from the server, so you need to use a method instead of updating on the client. This is also a good idea because the wrong action would occur if the client didn't have the complete set of documents.

Comment: Thanks. But can I do the "find -> insert / update" smarter or is that how it has to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a method on the server like this

```
Meteor.methods({
    'saveToCollection': function(collection, journal, article){
        if (global[collection].find({journal: journal}).count()) {
            global[collection].update(
                { journal: journal }, 
                { 
                    $addToSet: { article: article }
                }
            );          
        }
        else {
            global[collection].insert({ 
                journal: journal, 
                article: [article]
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```